# Removing android-support-v7-appcompat

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar

I was using the Android developer guide to learn. On my first run, I ran into a number of problems setting up the **v7 appcompat library** which caused more errors for the next steps ahead of the guide. I had to restart coding the guide.

However, I am not sure how to remove the support library (I want to start over), which is currently on the same directory of my app folder. I am using Eclipse IDE. Can I just delete it from the Package Explorer? Will that wipe the library clean? If not, how should I remove the library to re-learn?

Comment: Delete it from the folder, and check your build path in eclipse. also check the dependencies. Then clean, build maybe restart eclipse sometimes it can help.. no miracle for this ^^

Comment: I deleted the v7 appcompat library from the Package Explorer. I also removed the library via properties of my project. I think these were the steps to remove the build path. However, I am not sure how to check dependencies. Also, how do I perform a clean on this situation? Does build mean compile?

Comment: Well if you want to delete it from your project just make sure the lib isn't in the package dependencies or any other by checking the build paths. Build means compile and linking the files and object of your project into an executable.

Comment: You should check this out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542978/remove-v7-appcompat-folder/22543448#22543448